# IO.readlines with spaces included - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spacing, readlines

I'm new to Rails and I've a problem and I have no idea how to solve it. Tried with google but with no luck.

Basically I have a textfile that I use IO.readlines to read the file, put in an array and then have it printed out in my View. I got that working.

The problem is that the textfile I "read" have indentations and when I print it out in my view from the array the indentation spaces dont get included.

This is how the code looks like at the moment.

**Controller**

```
 @codefile = Codefile.find(session[:codefile_id]) 
  dir = @codefile.file.url.to_s 
  url = dirr.split("?")
  @fileLinesArray = IO.readlines('public' + url[0])
```

**View**

```
<ol>
<% @fileLinesArray.each do |x| %>
    <li><%= x %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

Maybe I'm not even supposed to use readlines? Anyway...
Very thankfull for any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is HTML ignores multiple spaces in code. If you check the HTML source you'll see the spaces are there but they aren't rendered.

You have to use the `<pre>` tag, which stands for "preformatted" to preserve whitespace:

```
<ol>
<% @fileLinesArray.each do |x| %>
    <li><pre><%= x %></pre></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

Also you'll probably want to change it to `<%= x.chomp %>` which will leave off the extra newline character.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you very much!